# Access modifier visibility in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa

There are 3 modifiers: @private, @protected (default) and @public. So if i define a instance variable as private then that should not be accessible from anywhere. 
For E.g. -

```
@interface A {
    @private
    NSString *a;
}
@property(nonatomic, retain) NSString *a;
```

Now inside implementation of some other interface/class B-

```
-(void)getSomeValue {
     A *object = [[A alloc] init];
     NSString *value = object.a;
     .........
 }
```

Here i am able to access instance variable, although i defined that as private.

It is a bit confusing, although when i look into details of this statement, then it is clear that it is calling the getter of a, but then also it seems confusing and it is against the concept of OOPS.

Anyone having any thought on this?

Comment: And @package which restricts visibility to a framework.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's not the instance variable you're accessing but the property you declared. Don't declare the property if you do not want the instance variable to be visible outside the class.

Comment: My question is basically if i am able to access private variable outside then what is significance of that?

Comment: Again, you are not accessing the private variable. You declared it to be a property of this class. So you generated a getter and a setter for it. The variable is still private. The access methods are not.

Comment: CodeBrickie - Thanks..now i got it...i think i am a bit confused with the syntax...

Answer (score 8):

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Visibility : NSObject {
@public    
    BOOL boolPublic;
@protected 
    BOOL boolProtected;
@private
BOOL boolPrivate;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL boolPublic;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL boolProtected;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL boolPrivate;

@end

@implementation Visibility

@synthesize boolPublic;
@synthesize boolProtected;
@synthesize boolPrivate;

@end

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    Visibility *visibility = [[Visibility alloc] init];

    visibility.boolPublic    = YES;
    visibility.boolProtected = YES;
    visibility.boolPrivate   = YES;

    // Place following NSLog()'s here

    [pool release];
}
```

Let's try this out

**Using the methods you define with @property/@synthesize**

```
NSLog(@"Accessors %d %d %d", visibility.boolPublic, visibility.boolProtected, visibility.boolPrivate);

=> 2012-01-08 17:46:40.226 Untitled[2592:707] Accessors 1 1 1
```

**Accessing @public ivar directly**

```
NSLog(@"Public %d", visibility->boolPublic);

=> 2012-01-08 17:46:40.228 Untitled[2592:707] Public 1
```

**Accessing @protected ivar directly**

```
NSLog(@"Protected %d", visibility->boolProtected);

=> error: instance variable 'boolProtected' is protected
=> NSLog(@"Protected %d", visibility->boolProtected);
=>                                    ^
```

**Accessing @private ivar directly**

```
NSLog(@"Private %d", visibility->boolPrivate);

=> error: instance variable 'boolPrivate' is private
=> NSLog(@"Private %d", visibility->boolPrivate);
=>                                  ^
```

When you are accessing using dot notation this:

```
visibility.boolPublic
```

is equivalent to:

```
[visibility boolPublic]; // <- This is a method call
```

Answer (score -2):

Because you set it as a @property and you claim it in header file. The variable you set as a @property will auto generate getter and setter for this variable and they are both public method to get or set it(variable is still private). If you really want to make the property as an private method, you should claim it in .m file and it will become private. You can only use this variable in the .m file.

For example, in your .h file

```
@interface ClassWithPrivateProperty : NSObject {
@private
    NSString* member;
}
- (void) trySettingPrivateProperty;
@end
```

in your .m file

```
#import "ClassWithPrivateProperty.h"

@interface ClassWithPrivateProperty ()
@property (nonatomic,retain) NSString* member; 
@end

@implementation ClassWithPrivateProperty
@synthesize member;
- (void) trySettingPrivateProperty {
    self.member = @"A Value";
    NSLog(@"myClass.member = %@", self.member);
}
@end
```

You can check more detail in [Private properties for iPhone Objective-C](http://swish-movement.blogspot.com/2009/05/private-properties-for-iphone-objective.html)

Edit:

Thanks for Abizern and Paul's comment, but in fact I got nothing compile error for this program.

I think RIP's question is "Why I set the variable in @private but I can still modify the variable like instance.variable"

The answer is although he set the variable as @private, but claim @property for variable in .h file also provide public methods getter and setter. So he can still get the instance variable use `instance.variable`. For OOP design pattern you should not expose your internals publicly. So if you want to use a variable privately only in its class and no one know it. And you still want to use getter and setter to access this variable in its class. you should claim @property in .m file like I did above. I claim the @property in .m file, it's a @interface extension(unnamed category). So you can make it "like" private. Because you cannot access this variable from anywhere outside this class. So it's just like a "private @property" that I mention about.

Two useful articles for you [Public Properties with Private Setters](http://theocacao.com/document.page/516) and [Private properties for iPhone Objective-C](http://swish-movement.blogspot.com/2009/05/private-properties-for-iphone-objective.html)

Comment: You can't make private `@property`'s. You can hide it's visibility but there is nothing to stop me calling `[instance member];` from anywhere.

Comment: Paul's right. You'll get a compiler warning, but there is nothing to prevent the message being sent.